# Отправка СМС-сообщений со своего номера через http запрос

Tags: php, sms

Хотелось бы узнать реально ли реализовать автоматическую отправку смс со своего номера на номера пользователей. Например, если пользователь зашел на сайт - хочу ему отправить смс об этом. Имею сим-карту Йоты, потому что дает безлимитные смс за 50 рублей/месяц. Так же есть простенький андроид смартфон. Как можно реализовать подобную идею?

Сайт на php, про https://github.com/synchrone/oms-php/ слышал, очевидно, но не уверен работает ли до сих пор, да и хотелось бы не только для Мегафона решение.

Comment: Ну, как минимум, зачем Вам это? Кто будет давать ради такого свой личный номер телефона?

Comment: @Alexxosipov очевидно, необходимо. Есть сайт с результатами киберспортивных матчей, хочу сделать возможность оповещать об избранных командах по смс.

Comment: ну есть море фирм, которые предоставляют такую услугу, удобный api для работы и т.п. В РБ, например - https://rocketsms.by/

Answer (score 1):

Конечно можно, идешь на сайт smsgateway24.com. регистрируешься, потом скачиваешь приложение с гугл плей https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.xatul.nicsms&hl=ru и отправляешь POST запросы на создание смс через API smsgateway24.com. Дальше телефон сам подхватывает твою смс и с твоей Йоты сим карты улетают смски кому ты хочешь.